# Strange key mapping in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, keymapping

I am new to Android studio, it seems to be great IDE. But I have found that it has really strange key and shortcut mapping. I am using Czech keyboard.

When I try to type ">"  by pressing `Right ALT + .` the symbol is not appearing, and I got message box that says `"Go to custom Region. There are no custom foldings regions in the current file."`

It is really strange behaviour, I have problem with writing many more characters like brackets,..... I tried to set keymap profiles to Visual Studio and more. But nothing seems to work. I didn't have any of these problems in any other IDE (Netbeans, Eclipse, Visual Studio, Xamarin)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add this line:

```
actionSystem.force.alt.gr=true
```

to this file:

```
...\Android\android-studio\bin\idea.properties
```

As written here:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91975

Comment: Or `Help/Edit custom properties`, so you don't need to search that file (which can be not existing yet) in current version of AS (3.3.2).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, well... its problem with "old" keyboards. Newer keyboards don't have `Alt Gr` keys and IDE doesn't count on this in default.

Solutions:

1. Buy a new keyboard with no `Alt Gr` on it (using right `Alt` instead of `Alt Gr` is working for me)
2. Go to `File -> Settings -> Keymap` and search for implementation - delete `Ctrl + Alt + B`, hit "Apply" and you can now use this shortcut for "{"
3. As already mentioned below... add following line to `..\<Android Studio folder>\bin\idea.properties`:

   > `actionSystem.force.alt.gr=true`

   (update) Since newer version of AS (not sure which one, should be 2.3.3+), you don't need to manually access the properties file. Go to `Help -> Edit Custom Properties` and add `actionSystem.force.alt.gr=true` there.

Comment: thumb up for solution #2 :-)

Comment: Agreed, solution #2 worked for me as well. You can also click the small magnifying glass next to the search bar and click CTRL + ALT + <Button that is not working for you> to find the function that is being called when you click ALT GR + <Button that is not working for you>.

Comment: Buy a new keyboard...
I have 1 year old logitech wireless keyboard with Alt Gr so...

Comment: What I ment was - buy a new keyboard with no "alt gr" on it :)

Comment: It's not a question if it's old (or old style) keyboard or not. For example all hungarian layout keyboards have the AltGr button, because a bunch of special characters are bound with it, since we don't have dedicated buttons for [], etc. We have some extra characters in the languare (ÖÜÓŐÚÉÁŰÍ) which takes up their own buttons, so we need to use the AltGr button to write []{}<>#&@ etc. characters. That being said, the best solution is the properties file (why isn't there an option for this in settings?) and not temper with the key bindings.

Comment: @Drusantia Well, you can now access the properties file from AS directly without going and search for it. I updated the answer. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Preferences -> Keymap and choose Mac OS X as Keymaps.

Answer (score 2):

I have been a long time Visual Studio user, so wanted to leverage all the keyboard shortcuts that I had picked up using Visual Studio.

On Android Studio, I first changed the Keymap to be Visual Studio. You can do this by using Alt+F7 on Windows and then search for Keymap.

By using the Visual Studio Keymap in Android studio, I got only debug related mapping, which was still a minority of what I use in Visual Studio.

So went ahead and added/modified some more mappings.
Here is the github link
https://github.com/vinayakg/VisualStudioKeymapforAndroidStudio/blob/master/settings.jar.

PR's welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As for '>' sign (AltGr + .) and Android Studio 1.0.1, go to File>Settings, choose Keymap in IDE Settings section, search for "GotoCustomRegion" item (it is located in MainMenu-Navigate) and remove its mapping (via context menu).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using macOS newest versions and have had weird behavior with the shortcuts, try this:

Go to Android Studio -> Preferences -> Keymap

Now change from "Mac OS X" to "Mac OS X 10.5+" and hit apply.

[image: Select Mac OS X 10.5+]