# Android Studio keeps inserting its own commands to bracelets and "|" button

Tags: android, android-studio

I can not do `Alt Gr + 7`or `Alt Gr + '-' (|) symbol`. When i try to do them, it either opens a new window or shrinks the block of code that my mouse cursor is currently in. In Android Studio ->`Settings->Keymaps`, i couldnt't find these shortcuts. What is the problem with android studio? how does it expect me to write an app without using `{` and `|` symbols? How can it steal important code shortcuts?

Comment: What OS are you using? Cannot reproduce with Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Many say adding force alt gr to idea.properties helps ;  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91975 . But there's alternatives too ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938618/strange-key-mapping-in-android-studio .

Comment: @1615903 Windows 8.1